# Separate the comma separated values in a dictionary to separate strings list

Tags: python, string, list, performance, dictionary

Input: `{'canada': 'america,usa', 'japan': 'tokio,Africa,Europe}`

Output: `{'canada': ['america','usa'], 'japan': ['tokio','Africa','Europe']}`

Something like this:

```py
Dictionary= dict(e.split(',') for e in input)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a dictionary comprehension to create the new dict.

```py
Dictionary= {k:e.split(',') for k,e in input.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in input:
    input[key] = list(input[key].split(','))
```